# What are Alternative's "some" and "many" useful for?

Tags: haskell, applicative, some-and-many, alternative-functor

[`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative), an extension of `Applicative`, declares `empty`, `<|>` and these two functions:

> One or more:
>
> ```
> some :: f a -> f [a]
> ```
>
> Zero or more:
>
> ```
> many :: f a -> f [a]
> ```
>
> If defined, `some` and `many` should be the least solutions of the equations:
>
> ```
> some v = (:) <$> v <*> many v
>
> many v = some v <|> pure []
> ```

I couldn't find an instance for which `some` and `many` are defined. **What is their meaning and practical use?** Are they used at all? I've been unable to grasp their purpose just from this definition.

**Update:** I'm not asking what is `Alternative`, just what are `some` and `many`

Comment: Although there are some nice answers here, however this question is a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203686/haskell-what-is-control-applicative-alternative-good-for), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671009/functions-from-alternative-type-class) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841511/haskell-some-and-many)

Comment: they are what it says: combinators for multiple application of (e.g.) a parser, collecting the results in a list. I provided the elementary example where the definitions are easily followed.

Comment: @WillNess Thank, I didn't think about parsers. Still what puzzles me is why they're included in `Alternative`, when these functions are undefined for the basic classes.

Comment: A duplicate question got [this very nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7681283/1013393).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tend to see them in `Applicative` parser combinator libraries.

```
a :: Parser [String]
a = some (string "hello")
```

and I see `many` used for purpose in the [default definitions of `Parsing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsers/0.9/doc/html/src/Text-Parser-Combinators.html#Parsing) in `parsers`.

I think Parsec being the primary example of a parser combinator library hides the use of `some`/`many` since it redefines things like `(<|>)`.

Answer (score 24):

*TL;DR:* `some` is one or more, `many` is 0 or more results collected from performing the same computation over and over by the familiar [*maximal munch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule. For this to make sense, some state passing (and alteration) must take place reducing the domain of possibilities somehow, otherwise it will repeat ad infinitum. And state passing and *parsing* are closely related.

---

An elementary example instance: with

```
import Control.Monad(Functor(..))
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

-- char string parser
newtype P a = P { runP :: String -> [(a,String)] }

-- runP (P p) s = p s

instance Functor P where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  fmap f (P q) = P (\s -> [ (f y,ys) | (y,ys) <- q s])

instance Applicative P where
  -- pure :: a -> f a
  pure x = P (\s -> [(x,s)])
  -- (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  P p <*> P q = P (\s -> [(x y, ys) | (x,xs) <- p s, (y,ys) <- q xs])

letter = P p where      -- sample parser
  p (x:xs) | isAlpha x = [(x,xs)]
  p _ = []
```

we have

> ```
> *Main Data.Char> runP letter "123"
> []
> *Main Data.Char> runP letter "a123"
> [('a',"123")]
> *Main Data.Char> runP ( (:) <$> letter <*> pure []) "a123"
> [("a","123")]
> *Main Data.Char> runP ( (:) <$> letter <*> ((:)<$>letter <*> pure []) ) "a123"
> []
> *Main Data.Char> runP ( (:) <$> letter <*> ((:)<$>letter <*> pure []) ) "ab123"
> [("ab","123")]   -- NOT NICE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -}
> ```

Then, with

```
instance Alternative P where
  -- (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
  P p <|> P q = P (\s-> p s ++ q s)
  -- empty :: f a   -- the identity of <|>
  empty = P (\s-> [])
```

we get

> ```
> *Main Data.Char> runP (many letter) "ab123"
> [("ab","123"),("a","b123"),("","ab123")]
> *Main Data.Char> runP (some letter) "ab123"
> [("ab","123"),("a","b123")]
>
> *Main Data.Char> runP (optional letter) "ab123"
> [(Just 'a',"b123"),(Nothing,"ab123")]
> *Main Data.Char> runP (optional letter) "123"
> [(Nothing,"123")]
>
> Prelude Main Data.Traversable> runP (sequenceA $ replicate 2 letter) "ab123"
> [("ab","123")]               --  NICE  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> -}
> ```

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: Off-topic, meta question: I noticed you have created the missing [haskell-alternative] tag. Some time ago, I had thought of doing the same, and even compiled a list of questions we might want to add it to, but got stuck pondering whether to combine MonadPlus and Alternative into a single tag (my instinctive inclination) or to keep them apart, and what to name the tag(s) (I had originally thought of [monadplus-and-alternative]). I would appreciate your opinion on those issues -- it could help me to finally make up my mind :)

Comment: @duplode I used "haskell-" there since "alternative" by itself seemed too vague and too general. with "monadplus-and-" there's indeed no *need* for it from that perspective. as to whether to join them together, do you have in your list many questions that would need *both* `haskell-alternative` and `haskell-monadplus`? if not, you could define the latter and tag those few with the both of them. if yes, you could rename the current tag (by simply retagging its current 11 question) to either `monadplus-and-alternative` or `haskell-monadplus-and-alternative`. or is your list too short  (contd.)

Comment: ... to be a valid indicator?

Comment: @WillNess Checking my spreadsheet, I found 20 Alternative candidates that are also on the MonadPlus list, out of a total of 93. While that's significant overlap, it should be workable to have separate tags. And yes, the Alternative tag sure need a prefix. Ideally, I'd have something other than "haskell-" for the benefit of hypothetical PureScript/Scala/etc. questions (I'll likely  use [monadplus] for the other tag for that reason), but I can't think of anything better ([alternative-typeclass], in particular, isn't very good). Anyway, I'll get on with the retagging soon. Thanks!

Comment: @duplode maybe `functor-alternative`? (and even `functor-monadplus`??)

Comment: @WillNess Good idea, [alternative-functor] sounds great!

Comment: @WillNess Retagging done! With 64 questions so far, [tag:alternative-functor] has come along nicely. At 39 questions, 14 of them shared with [alternative-functor], [tag:monadplus] doesn't feel as solid, though [this gem of an unresolved controversy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15722906/2751851) is perhaps worth the price of admission already.

Comment: @duplode great and necessary (and thankless) work! the numbers are quite nice, BTW, the both of them; I've encountered quite a few tags with a dozen questions or less, which felt necessary nevertheless, so 39 is not a small number at all. :)

Answer (score 19):

In the STM Applicative, `some` would mean: Keep trying until it succeeds at least once, and then keep doing it until it fails.  `many` would mean: Do this as many times as you can until failure.

Comment: Neat, never thought about that!

Answer (score 6):

Will provided a good example motivating the use of those methods, but you seem to still have a misunderstanding about type classes.

A type class definition lists the type signatures for the methods that exist for *all instances* of the type class. It may also provide *default implementations* of those methods, which is what is happening with Alternative's **some** and **many** methods.

In order to be valid instances, *all* of the methods have to be defined for the instance. So the ones that you found that did not *specifically* define instances for **some** or **many** used the *default* implementations, and the code for them is exactly as listed in your question.

So, just to be clear, **some** and **many** are indeed defined and can be used with all **Alternative** instances thanks to the default definitions given with the type class definition.

Comment: I understand all that. To clarify, the definitions of `some` and `many` for the most basic types such as `[]` and `Maybe` just loop. So although the definition of `some` and `many` for them is valid, it has no meaning.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I really liked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7681283/849891) (thanks, is7s).

Comment: @WillNess Indeed, this answer is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

The [`regex-applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) package defines [a custom `many` method](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative-0.3.3.1/docs/src/Text.Regex.Applicative.Interface.html#line-23) for the [`RE`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative-0.3.3.1/docs/Text-Regex-Applicative.html#t:RE) (regular expression) type. Regular expressions, and therefore `RE` parsers, must be finite in size, so using default definitions for both `some` and `many` would lead to infinite loops! Fortunately, `many` is just the classic regular expression `*`.

The package also includes a definition of `some`, but that looks too much like the default definition to be anything interesting.