# why Alternative's some and many are infinite recursive functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, typeclass, some-and-many, alternative-functor

I was looking at `Alternative` typeclass in haskell and I was playing with it in ghci when I issued this

```
some (Just 2)
```

It hanged, I looked in the source code of Alternative, Alternative's some and many default definition is this :

```
some :: f a -> f [a]
some v = some_v
  where
    many_v = some_v <|> pure []
    some_v = (fmap (:) v) <*> many_v

-- | Zero or more.
many :: f a -> f [a]
many v = many_v
  where
    many_v = some_v <|> pure []
    some_v = (fmap (:) v) <*> many_v
```

It's obvious that `some_v` and `many_v` are indirectly infinitely recursive, and they aren't defined in terms of `empty` and `<|>`.

If they must be defined by the instance then they shouldn't have default definition, right ? and since `Maybe` doesn't define them my statement above hanged which seems strange to me since it isn't mentioned in the docs.

So why were they defined like that ? is There something I'm missing ?

Comment: `many Nothing` and `some Nothing` work fine. What did you expect `some (Just 2)` to do?

Comment: @melpomene well `Just [2]` or `exception : unimplemented`

Comment: `Just [2]` is semantically wrong. It would have to be `Just [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]` but that computation never finishes.

Comment: @melpomene hmmm if it is `Just [2,2,2,2,...]` then wouldn't `take 2 <$> (some (Just 2))` return some results ? (it hanged with me)

Comment: No, because it can't actually return that (at least with the current definition it has to "run actions" until `v` turns `empty` at some point).  Hmm.

Comment: Related: [What are Alternative's “some” and “many” useful for?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18108608/1333025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alternative instance for Maybe is as follows:

```
instance Alternative Maybe where
    empty = Nothing
    Nothing <|> r = r
    l       <|> _ = l
```

It defines `empty` and `(<|>)`, leaving `some` and `many` as their default implementations.

Using `many` and `some` makes sense when the `Alternative` can succeed or fail for "external reasons" not contained in the value itself. The typical example is parsers: you try to parse integers repeatedly from an input stream, until an integer isn't found and `empty` is returned.

But with `Just 2`, the Alternative "always succeeds", so to speak. There's nothing external to the value that can make it "fail" and finish the computation. So it goes into an infinite loop.